# Guard gem won't notice file deletions on OSX

Tags: ruby, events, filesystems, delete-file, guard

I'm developing a plugin to the Guard Ruby gem on OS X and I'm struggling with getting the file deletion event work. All fires up nicely when a file is modified or created, but when it is deleted the Guard won't notice it at all.

I have tried the `--watch-all-modifications` flag with no success.

In my class that inherits from `Guard::Guard` I have a `run_on_deletion(paths)` method with lots of `puts`, which should make it.

I have tried Guard versions 0.10.0 and 0.9.4.

Am I missing something?